# "" give error while parsing string into the json

Tags: javascript, json, string

I am storing my data in string.
for eg -

```
    var xyz = '{ Product : ['    
    xyz = xyz + { id:"1",name:"abc"}  //this generates via loop
    xyz = xyz + ']}';
    $scope.data = JSON.parse(xyz);
```

but this is giving me error. It is appending "" to my string and formatting like

```
JSON.parse("{ Product : [{ id:"1",name:"abc"}]}")
```

How to get rid of this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not *ever* try to construct JSON by concatenating strings. Use `JSON.stringify` instead.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "_It is appending "" to my string_".

Comment: There is no reason to create your object as a string and then parsing it

Answer (score 0):

You need escape " with \". and use " with keys of jso.

I think you better create the object and the arrays and later transform them into json.
Example:

```
var obj = {name : "Marcos"};
obj.products = [];

for (....){
   obj.products.push( {id: x} );
}
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

It's more natural to program and much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to create your object as a string and then parsing it

If you need a loop, loop and push

```js
const data = {
  Product: []
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  data.Product.push({
    "id": i,
    name: "abc"
  });
}
console.log(data)
```